# How do I chain update and insert expressions with sqlalchemy core in postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to split rows in a postgres database on a range column using sqlalchemy core but I can't seem to figure out how to do so without storing temporary information in memory.

Basic structure of the table / data:

```py
import psycopg2.extras as pgx
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql as sap

table = sa.Table(
    'table', sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column('value', sa.Integer),
    sa.Column('range', sap.INT8RANGE))

conn.execute(table.insert(), [{'value': 1, 'range': pgx.NumericRange(1, None)}])
```

What I'm trying to do is split the row into two rows with different range values. I can do this with update returning and then a separate insert across the results in the following manner:

```py
split_point = 3
left_range = sa.func.int8range(sa.func.lower(table.c.range), split_point)
return_columns = [c for c in table.c]
return_keys = [c.name for c in return_columns]
capped_rows = conn.execute(
    table.update()
    .where(table.c.range.contains(sa.cast(split_point, sa.BigInteger)))
    .values({'range': left_range})
    .returning(return_columns))

new_rows = []
for row in capped_rows:
    new_row = dict(zip(return_keys, row))
    new_row['range'] = pgx.NumericRange(split_point, None)
    new_rows.append(new_row)

if new_rows:
    conn.execute(table.insert(), new_rows)
```

This results in expected output of the form:

```py
expected = [
    {'value': 1, 'range': pgx.NumericRange(1, 3)},
    {'value': 1, 'range': pgx.NumericRange(3, None)},
]
```

Unforuntately, doing things this way requires that I load a large amount of data into memory in the new_rows list, which also requires me to move data in and out of the database.

Is there any way to achieve the same result by chaining the update into the insert or otherwise do everything on server side?

I've tried using table.insert().from_select but I can' seem to find something to put inside the from_select that works.